# Rule that allows for refactoring: $ -\frac{t^2}{2} + t \to \frac{t}{2}(-t+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I refactor $-\frac{t^2}{2} + t$ to $\frac{t}{2}(-t+2)$?

I am not understanding the rule that allows for the refactor.

I did some substitution of variables and constants and found that the denominator becomes a part of the second expression of the refactored equation, but I am stuck at that part.

Comment: What is `t^/2`? Please use LaTeX

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig                                                                                            TY. I was unaware of the typesetting issues.

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, @GoodDeeds used the distributive law $a(b + c) = ab + ac$ with $a = \frac{t}{2}$, $b = -t$, and $c = 2$ in the reverse direction.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to both of you. I thought I had covered this stuff well enough but obviously I need to recover the material until it's internalized...

Comment: First divide by $t$ and then by $2$, so such division is by distribution law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\frac{t^2}{2}+t=t\left(-\frac{t}{2}+1\right)=t\left(-\frac{t+2}{2}\right)=\frac t2(-t+2)$$

Comment: Great. Nice, simple and to the point. TY.